# Is there any way to change image in tailwindcss when dark mode toggled?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, tailwind-css, darkmode

I was looking around, but couldn't find any related Q&A out there. I'm building a project in ReactJS with tailwindCSS, and implementing dark mode to the site. Everything works fine, but now I have some issues with a background image.
I have set the two image in the `tailwind.config.js`

```
  darkMode: 'class',
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: (theme) => ({
        'code': "url('/src/components/About/coding-bg-dark.png')",
        'light-code': "url('/src/components/About/lightcode.png')",
       })
    },
  },
```

and have the classNames on the decent section

```
<section id='introduction' className="bg-code dark:bg-light-code bg-cover bg-fixed flex flex-wrap content-center w-full md:h-screen">
```

but when I toggle dark mode, the image doesn't change, the dark image stays on the light mode. Any idea how could I go around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `darkMode: 'media'` in your `tailwind.config.js`, as well as extend the background image's variants to include dark mode. Here is an example `tailwind.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  darkMode: 'media',
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: (theme) => ({
        'image-one':
          "url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1629651480694-edb8451b31aa?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=668&q=80')",
        'image-two':
          "url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1629651726230-6430554a8890?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2734&q=80')",
      }),
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: ['dark'],
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Then it should work. You can see a working example [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/0vogrJfmGV).

Comment: Thank you @Santeri-Sarle ! Yes, the problem was that I missed the extension of the variants from the `tailwind.config.js`, so luckily was just a one-liner.
I am using class in the darkMode module, so the user can toggle between the light and dark mode and doesn't depend on system preferences, but it works with class as well. Have a good one, and thank you again.

Comment: Ah, yep, I missed that you already had `darkMode: 'class'`, but good that you got it to work regardless!

Comment: If you do it like that, you can't control the image via bundlers like webpack.

Answer (score 2):

I`m using nuxt with @nuxtjs/color-mode for the said features. For me, this is more robust and easier to maintain

```
<img
        v-show="$colorMode.value === 'dark'"
        src="~/assets/images/index/bg-1.jpg"
        class="absolute w-full"
        style="height: 50vh"
      />
      <span
        v-show="$colorMode.value === 'dark'"
        class="
          absolute
          w-full
          h-full
          bg-gradient-to-t
          from-gray-800
          to-transparent
        "
      />
      <img
        v-show="$colorMode.value === 'light'"
        src="~/assets/images/index/bg-2.jpg"
        class="absolute w-full"
        style="height: 50vh"
      />
      <span
        v-show="$colorMode.value === 'light'"
        class="
          absolute
          w-full
          h-full
          bg-gradient-to-tl
          from-gray-900
          to-transparent
        "
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve the same using `div`. You can set the `background-image` of the div and adjust the `background-size` to `100%`. Now with the help of the `dark` CSS class, you can specify different `background-image` for dark and light modes.

**Normally, this trick is performed for setting different background images for light and dark modes on websites.**

**HTML:**

```html
<div className="bg-Pic dark:bg-Pic-dark w-36 h-36"></div>
```

**Custom CSS:**

```css
.dark .dark\:bg-Pic-dark {
  background-image: url("../images/pic-dark.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.bg-Pic {
  background-image: url("../images/pic-light.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: That's right, and would work as well. However Tailwind would lose its primary purpose of not using CSS

Comment: It's kind of like a brute-force approach. Maybe would be best to use it if no other solutions work.

Comment: Yes, I would agree with that!